# How to modify values in csv table using csv helper c#

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

I have a question in trying to parse a csv file, the given file is formatted like:

```
Header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
value4,,value5,value6
```

In row 3, there is an extra comma after value4, where there should only be one, and I am trying to remove it or replace it with a blank space so the file will look like:

```
value4,value5,value6
```

Here is my code so far:

```
                var textwriter = Console.Out;
                using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textwriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                using (var reader = new StringReader(@"csvfile.csv"))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                    csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvTable_Headers_Map>();
                    csv.Read();
                    csv.ReadHeader();
                    csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0].StartsWith("__") || row[0].StartsWith("T");
//above line is used to ignore records in real files 
                   var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvTable_Headers>();
                   csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
                }
```

Would there be a way like in the ShouldSkipRecord line where I could detect if there is an extra comma, then remove it? I also tried using an if statement like:

```
if(records.Contains("value4,")
{
// I know this logic does not work, trying to see if there is a workaround
replace("value4,") with("value4")
}
```

So with this, would there be a way to remove the extra comma after value4?

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening the file differently, something like this:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"csvfile.csv");
fileContent = fileContent.Replace(",,", ",");
var reader = new StringReader(fileContent);
```

and then continue with your implementation

Comment: Oh I tried that, but records isnt a string, it is of type Ienumerable

Comment: Updated my answer, with a different type of solution, you could try opening the file different, just to get the content as simple string, then you replace the double  `commas` and then move to the same sting reader you're using